# How to select items in prisma with date GTE > current date

Tags: node.js, prisma

Hi there I'm new and prisma and trying to select future dates in prisma and not grab any 'expired' days.

I'm seeing in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/date-types) that there is a `prisma.now()` but cant see it in the console when I log out `cosole.log(prisma)`

Does anybody know a good solution to this?

My `created_at` is grabbing this format: `2022-01-13 12:00`

```
app.get("/ques", async function (req, res) {
  console.log("PRISMA", prisma.NOW());
  const allQues = await prisma.que.findMany({
    where: {
      created_at: {
        gte: prisma.NOW(),
      },
    },
  });
  res.status(200).send(allQues);
});
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure that such thing even exists? (`prisma.NOW()`)

`now()` is just a function that you can use in your schema file to set the default value, for example:

```
model User {
  registeredAt     DateTime @default(now())
}
```

In your app code you can just use regular Javascript `Date` object, for example:

```
  const allQues = await prisma.que.findMany({
    where: {
      created_at: {
        // new Date() creates date with current time and day and etc.
        gte: new Date()
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: what if I want to get exact date data if any? not gte, gt, lte, or lt?

Comment: You just do `created_at: new Date()`

Comment: could this be a problem if the application server time is different than the database server time?